# Extracting relational data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm trying to build a small application in `laravel 5.4` where I'm having a `contacts` table, `companies` table, `interactions` table and `users` table each with their respective models. An `Interaction` is being created by the `User` where there are `client_contact`, `contact`, `user` participating. Each client_contact and contact shares the same model and belongs to a company which have type in their column for example Investor, Research, Corporate etc. Now I'm trying to generate a report where interaction done by a user with Investors. First of all let me show you my models:

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;


    public function interactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Interaction');
    }

    public function clients()
    {
        //Each user has been assigned a particular client 
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_user', 'user_id', 'company_id');
    }

}
```

**Contacts Model:**

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, DataViewer;

    public function company()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_contact','contact_id', 'company_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function interactions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interaction', 'contact_interaction','contact_id', 'interaction_id');
    }

    public function clientInteractions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interaction', 'contact_client_interaction','contact_id', 'interaction_id');
    }
}
```

**Company Model:**

```
class Company extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, DataViewer;

    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'company_contact', 'company_id','contact_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'company_user', 'company_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

**Interaction Model:**

```
class Interaction extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function stellarParticipants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function clientsAssociation()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'contact_client_interaction',  'interaction_id', 'contact_id')->withPivot('company_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function contactsAssociation()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'contact_interaction',  'interaction_id', 'contact_id')->withPivot('company_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

Now in my **ReportController:** I'm doing something like this:

```
 public function getAnalystInvestor(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->id);
    $interactions = Interaction::whereHas('contactsAssociation', function ($query3) {
        $query3->whereHas('company', function ($query4) {
            $query4->where('type', 'like', '%'.'Investor'.'%');
        });
    })->whereHas('user', function ($query1) use($user) {
        $query1->where('name', '=', $user->name);
    })->orWhereHas('stellarParticipants', function ($query2) use($user) {
        $query2->where('name', '=', $user->name);
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->take(50)
    ->with(['contactsAssociation', 'clientsAssociation', 'stellarParticipants'])
    ->get();

    return response()->json(['interactions' => $interactions], 200);

}
```

But I'm unable to get the desired results, still some of the data are displaying which is not investors. I also tried:

```
$interactions = Interaction::whereHas('user', function ($query1) use($user) {
        $query1->where('name', '=', $user->name);
    })->orWhereHas('stellarParticipants', function ($query2) use($user) {
        $query2->where('name', '=', $user->name);
    })->whereHas('contactsAssociation', function ($query3) {
        $query3->whereHas('company', function ($query4) {
            $query4->where('type', 'like', '%'.'Investor'.'%');
        });
    })
```

Where user filters are assigned first but its not displaying as desired. Help me out with this.

Comment: Just create a SQL view and create model forit. You are running into performance troubles with that amount of queries created with ORM

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to chain your query, similar to this:

```
$cfs = \App\Service::with('items', 'required_services', 'supported_services')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('stm', 11)
                ->orWhere('stm', 17)
                ->orWhere('stm', 31);
        })
        ->where('lifecycle_id', '!=', 12)
        ->where('type', 'Customer Facing')
        ->orderBy('service_full_name')
        ->get();
```

I don't really understand the report you are developing, but hopefully this helps you.